# Mantener el borde de un boton c#

Tags: c#

Quisiera saber si alguien tiene el conocimiento de como puedo mantener el color del borde de un botón después de que vuelvo al botón de inicio y regreso al formulario.

Como lo tengo en este momento es así:
1 Tengo un form1 el cual es el principal, en este hay un botón que me lleva a otro formulario donde esta el botón el cual tiene el siguiente código:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)       
            {
                if (toggle == true)
                {
                    this.button1.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.Red;//con click deja el borde rojo

                    toggle = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.button1.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.Black;//con doble click deja el borde negro
                    toggle = true;
                }
```

2 en el form2 tengo un botón para volver al home

```
 this.Hide();
```

3 cuando vuelvo al form1 y vuelvo al form2 ya no tiene el borde de color rojo

Hay alguna forma de poder mantener ese borde?

Muchas graias.

Comment: Cómo y dónde tienes declarada la variable `toggle`?

Comment: Seria útil que mostrarás el código del evento del botón del ’form1' desde donde llamas al 'form2' para regresar,  el error debe estar allí.

Comment: Cordial saludo, Pablo Gutiérrez,
La variable toggle la declare en el form2 y la utilizo en el if para el cambio de color en los bordes de los botones a los que s eles da clic

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: //Abrimos el form2
            Form2 menu_fallas1 = new Form2();
            menu_fallas1.ShowDialog();

            //sumar en el array cada vez que se crea
            arrayBoton = new Button[contadorBotones + 1];

            //recuperar los datos
            string textBoton = Form2.textoboton;
            Image imagen = Form2.imagen;
            int alto = Form2.alto;
            int ancho = Form2.ancho;
         
            //crear boton
            Button nuevoboton = new Button();

            //asignar texto - propiedades
            nuevoboton.Text = textBoton;

Comment: Edison, Ese segmento de código que está en los comentarios a qué método pertenece?. Te sugiero [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/402751/edit) tu pregunta para agregarle el código que incluiste en los comentarios.